# Java try-with-resource - log error with closing of resource

Tags: java, try-catch

I have the following :-

```
private static String loadString(File f) {
    StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
    Reader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(...));
        ...
        while (reader.read(data) >= 0) {
            ... 
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(....);
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn(....);
        }
    }
    return results.toString();
}
```

I want to use Java 7 try-with-resources to automatically close the resource, but would also like to maintain the warning being logged when there is an error in closing down the stream, and this log message will be different to that logged above when an exception is caught after being thrown from the try body. 
What is the most elegant way of doing this, as I think the fact that the try clause and the closing down of the resource both throw the same exception could make it tricky to maintain these 2 separate logger warnings  ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an exception is thrown when closing the resource, during the processing of another exception thrown from inside the `try` block, the exception is suppressed and added to the initial exception.

If the logging frame supports suppressed exceptions, and you give the exception to the logging framework, then you don't need to do anything.

Otherwise, you need to log the suppressed exceptions yourself, like this:

```
private static String loadString(File f) {
    StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)))) {
        ...
        while (reader.read(data) >= 0) {
            ... 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(....);
        for (Throwable ex : e.getSuppressed())
            logger.warn(....);
    }
    return results.toString();
}
```

Comment: What if `close()` threw an exception but the try body didn't? I think the wrong warning would be logged.

Comment: @SalvatoreElia Only if you insist on each logging statement to specify a difference message, but why would that be needed? In either case, it's an IOException, the code failed, the exception will specify why, and the stacktrace will specify where.

Comment: I have no idea why, but the question says that the log messages are different.

Comment: @SalvatoreElia I read that as it'll be different because the exception is different, not because the log text would be different. The log message will be the same whether the exception is from the constructor or the `read()` method, so why should the exception from the `close()` method need to be different?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding. When I read the question, it sounds like the log messages are different but the exceptions are the same ('2 separate log warnings').

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andreas, but Salvatore is correct in that the log messages are different but the exceptions are the same.

Comment: @user396707 If the log messages *must* be different, then of course you can't use try-with-resources. I just don't understand *why* they would need to be different. That makes no sense to me, since they are all just failures of the I/O system (file system).